# How to handle AngularJs chart with External Json Values

Tags: angularjs, json, chart.js

I need to create a chart js with external JSON data, here i tried with chartjs in Aungularjs

```
<script>

                            var barChartData = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            backgroundColor: "#09a",
          data: ["100", "150", "50", "120", "75", "250", "31"],
        }]

    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: barChartData,
        });

    };


</script>
```

here the JSON was handled internally with the variable **barChartData** and assign to **data: barChartData**, How can I do the same with the external JSON ?

Comment: external json means json fetched from an ajax request. right? 
Create your Chart when that json is ready.

Comment: I have the same values assigned to barchartdata in a separate file **data.json**, now i have to get the values from that file and assign  the same to the variable 'barchartdata' like 'var barChartData =  "/data.json"'